# Firefox and IE can't modify cssRules

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I need to change existent global CSS rules then I access **document.styleSheets**, obtain my rule and modify it.

I modify the selector by accessing the **selectorText** property.

CSS code

```
<style type="text/css">
    .class {
        color: #230020;
    }
</style>
```

JavaScript code

```
var rule = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0]; // obtain the first rule.

/* Chrome, Opera, Safari */
rule.selectorText; // returns ".class"
rule.selectorText = ".another-class";
rule.selectorText; // returns ".another-class", then it works and the rule changed.
```

My problem is that in all versions of Firefox and Internet Explorer, the property **selectorText** seems to be read-only.

```
/* Internet Explorer, Edge, and Firefox */
rule.selectorText; // returns ".class"
rule.selectorText = ".another-class";
rule.selectorText; // returns ".class", It remains as it was.
```

How can I make it work on Mozilla Firefox, Microsoft Internet Explorer and Edge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule/selectorText), `selectorText` is meant to be read-only:

> The CSSRule.selectorText property gets the textual representation of the selector for the rule set. This is implemented in a readonly manner; to set stylesheet rules dynamically, see Using dynamic styling information.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a cross-browser way to change the selector of a CSS rule. If that is your goal, you can try deleting the entire rule and replacing it with a new one by using the same rule index, you'll just have to include all of the rule properties along with the selector, like this:

```
var cssText = document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].style.cssText;
document.styleSheets[0].deleteRule(0);
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.another-class { ' + cssText + ' }', 0);
```

Works for me in Firefox and other browsers. See [insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) and [deleteRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule%20%22deletRule).

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how you can cache the original style properties so you don't have to re-write them.

Comment: This isn’t accurate — check the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSRule). The FF bug is still around, though it does allegedly work in IE with caveats. I’ve corrected the MDN article.